# onclick event, triggered onload

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to simulate a pop-up message, which shall be shown when the form is correctly submitted. The code I wrote works, but my Javascript function, which simulates the pop-up, is also invoked on window load for some reason. I post the code, hoping you can help to find my mistake:

page contact.php:

```
<section>
<div class = "contentContainer">
    <h1 class = "mainTitle" >
        Contact us
    </h1>
    <div class = "innerContainer">
        <p class = "content">
            You can contact us through the form below. We can arrange a Skype meeting without any costs for you.
        </p>
        <p class = "content" id = "response"></p>
        <form id = "contact" class = "shadowRadius" action = "" method = "POST" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label for "firstName">Name*:</label> </td>
                    <td> <img src = "<?php echo ( ROOT."img/pages/contact/user.png" ); ?>" class = "transparent" alt = "Name"> </td>
                    <td> <input id = "firstName" class = "input" type = "text" placeholder = "Your full name" onBlur = "return bCheckName()" required > </td>
                    <td id = "nameResponse"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for "companyName">Company*:</label></td>
                    <td><img src = "<?php echo ( ROOT."img/pages/contact/company.png" ); ?>" alt = "company name"></td>
                    <td><input id = "companyName" class = "input" type = "text" placeholder = "Your company's name" onBlur = "return bCheckCompany()" required></td>
                    <td id = "companyResponse"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for "email">E-mail*:</label></td>
                    <td><img src = "<?php echo ( ROOT."img/pages/contact/email.png" ); ?>" alt = "e-mail" ></td>
                    <td><input id = "email" class = "input" type = "mail" placeholder = "Your e-mail" onBlur = "return bCheckMail()" required></td>
                    <td id = "mailResponse"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label for "subject">Subject*:</label> </td>
                    <td> <img src = "<?php echo ( ROOT."img/pages/contact/subject.png" ); ?>" class = "transparent" alt = "subject"> </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input list = "subject" name = "subject" class = "input" type = "text" placeholder = "Select subject" onBlur = "return bCheckSubject()" required>
                        <datalist id = "subject" >
                            <option value = "information" >
                            <option value = "skype meeting" >
                            <option value = "web testing" >
                            <option value = "other" >
                        </datalist>
                    </td>
                    <td id = "subjectResponse"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for "message">Message*:</label></td>
                    <td><img src = "<?php echo ( ROOT."img/pages/contact/text.png" ); ?>" class = "transparent" alt = "message" ></td>
                    <td><textarea id = "message" placeholder = "Type your message here" onKeyUp = "vCountChars()" onpaste = "vCountChars()" onBlur = "return bCheckMessage()" required></textarea></td>
                    <td id = "messageResponse"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><p id = "count" class = "normal">Remaining characters: 2000</p></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><div class = "g-recaptcha" data-sitekey = "6Lf6PygUAAAAAAy3fddIW5KBWoP37hShGrwbbIDD" ></div></td>
                    <td id = "captchaResponse" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type = "submit" class = "send" value = "Submit" name = "submit" onClick = "return bSubmit()" ></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <p class = "content">(*) The field is mandatory</p>
        <div id = "darkSide">
        </div><!--end of darkSide -->
        <div id = "pop-up" class = "shadowRadius">
            <img src = "<?php echo ( ROOT."img/pages/contact/true.png" ); ?>" alt = "OK">
            <p class = "normal">Your request is successfully submitted!!!</p>
            <div class = "clear">
            </div>
            <input type = "button" id = "accept" class = "shadowRadius" value = "OK" onClick = "vToggle()">
        </div><!--end of pop-up -->
    </div><!--end of innerContainer -->
</div><!--end of contentContainer -->
```

The javascript code is contained in a file called form.js:

```
function bCheckName ()
{
// It checks if the browser can allow a http request 
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    // for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// It takes the name from the form
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var datastring = "firstName=" + encodeURIComponent ( firstName );

// It opens the request to thye server
xhttp.open ( "POST", "../form/formValidation.php", true );

// It sets the header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// It sends the data to the server
xhttp.send( datastring );

// It takes the responde from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( !( xhttp.responseText == "" ))
        {
            var string      = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 0, 2 );
            var response    = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 5 );

            if ( string == "OK")
            {
                document.getElementById("nameResponse").innerHTML           = '<img id = "img1" src = "../img/pages/contact/true.png" alt = "correct answer" >';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("nameResponse").innerHTML           = '<img src = "../img/pages/contact/error.png" alt = "wrong answer">';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("nameResponse").innerHTML = "";
        }

    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function bCheckCompany ()
{
/* It checks if the browser can allow a http request */
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    // for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// It takes the name from the form
var companyName = document.getElementById("companyName").value;
var datastring = "companyName=" + encodeURIComponent ( companyName );

// It opens the request to thye server
xhttp.open ( "POST", "../form/formValidation.php", true );

// It sets the header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// It sends the data to the server
xhttp.send( datastring );

// It takes the responde from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( !( xhttp.responseText == "" ))
        {
            var string      = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 0, 2 );
            var response    = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 5 );

            if ( string == "OK")
            {
                document.getElementById("companyResponse").innerHTML        = '<img id = "img2" src = "../img/pages/contact/true.png" alt = "correct answer" >';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("companyResponse").innerHTML        = '<img src = "../img/pages/contact/error.png" alt = "wrong answer">';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response; 
            }

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("companyResponse").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function bCheckMail ()
{
/* It checks if the browser can allow a http request */
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    // for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// It takes the name from the form
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var datastring = "email=" + encodeURIComponent ( email );

// It opens the request to thye server
xhttp.open ( "POST", "../form/formValidation.php", true );

// It sets the header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// It sends the data to the server
xhttp.send( datastring );

// It takes the responde from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if (!( xhttp.responseText == "" ))
        {
            var string      = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 0, 2 );
            var response    = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 5 );

            if ( string == "OK")
            {
                document.getElementById("mailResponse").innerHTML           = '<img id = "img3" src = "../img/pages/contact/true.png" alt = "correct answer" >';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("mailResponse").innerHTML           = '<img src = "../img/pages/contact/error.png" alt = "wrong answer">';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("mailResponse").innerHTML = "";
        }

    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function bCheckSubject ()
{
/* It checks if the browser can allow a http request */
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    // for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// It takes the name from the form
var subject = document.getElementsByName("subject")[0].value;
var datastring = "subject=" + encodeURIComponent ( subject );

// It opens the request to thye server
xhttp.open ( "POST", "../form/formValidation.php", true );

// It sets the header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// It sends the data to the server
xhttp.send( datastring );

// It takes the responde from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( !( xhttp.responseText == "" ))
        {
            var string      = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 0, 2 );
            var response    = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 5 );

            if ( string == "OK")
            {
                document.getElementById("subjectResponse").innerHTML        = '<img id = "img4" src = "../img/pages/contact/true.png" alt = "correct answer" >';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("subjectResponse").innerHTML        = '<img src = "../img/pages/contact/error.png" alt = "wrong answer">';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("subjectResponse").innerHTML = "";
        }

    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function bCheckMessage ()
{
// It checks if the browser can allow a http request 
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    // for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// It takes the name from the form
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var datastring = "message=" + encodeURIComponent ( message );

// It opens the request to thye server
xhttp.open ( "POST", "../form/formValidation.php", true );

// It sets the header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// It sends the data to the server
xhttp.send( datastring );

// It takes the responde from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( !( xhttp.responseText == "" ))
        {
            var string      = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 0, 2 );
            var response    = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 5 );

            if ( string == "OK")
            {
                document.getElementById("messageResponse").innerHTML        = '<img id = "img5" src = "../img/pages/contact/true.png" alt = "correct answer" >';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("messageResponse").innerHTML        = '<img src = "../img/pages/contact/error.png" alt = "wrong answer">';
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML               = response; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("messageResponse").innerHTML = "";
        }

    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function bSubmit ()
{
// It disables the button for avoiding multiple requets
document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = true;

// It checks if the browser can allow a http request 
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) 
{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    // for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// It takes the input from the form
var firstName   = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var companyName = document.getElementById("companyName").value;
var email       = document.getElementById("email").value;
var subject     = document.getElementsByName("subject")[0].value;
var message     = document.getElementById("message").value;
var captcha     = document.getElementsByClassName("g-recaptcha")[0].getAttribute("data-sitekey");
var datastring  = "firstName=" + encodeURIComponent ( firstName ) + "&companyName=" + encodeURIComponent ( companyName ) +
                  "&email="    + encodeURIComponent ( email )     + "&subject="     + encodeURIComponent ( subject )     +
                  "&message="  + encodeURIComponent ( message )   + "&captcha="     + encodeURIComponent ( captcha );

// It opens the request to thye server
xhttp.open ( "POST", "../form/formValidation.php", true );

// It sets the header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// It sends the data to the server
xhttp.send( datastring );

// It takes the responde from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if ( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        // It enables the button
        document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].disabled = false;

        var string      = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 0, 2 );
        var response    = xhttp.responseText.substr ( 5 );

        if ( string == "OK")
        {
            /*vToggle(); I have commented it, in order to isolate tthe problem. */
            var dad     = document.getElementById("nameResponse");
            var son     = document.getElementById("img1");
            dad.removeChild ( son );
            dad         = document.getElementById("companyResponse");
            son         = document.getElementById("img2");
            dad.removeChild ( son );
            dad         = document.getElementById("mailResponse");
            son         = document.getElementById("img3");
            dad.removeChild ( son );
            dad         = document.getElementById("subjectResponse");
            son         = document.getElementById("img4");
            dad.removeChild ( son );
            dad         = document.getElementById("messageResponse");
            son         = document.getElementById("img5");
            dad.removeChild ( son );
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML           = response; 
        }
    }
}

return false;
```

}

```
function vCountChars ()
{
var MAX = 2000;
var usedChars = document.getElementById("message").value.length;
var remainChars = MAX - document.getElementById("message").value.length;
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Remaining characters: " + remainChars;

if ( remainChars <= 0 )
{
    document.getElementById("message").value = document.getElementById("message").value.substr(0, MAX);
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Remaining characters: 0";
    document.getElementById("count").style.color = "red";
}
else
{
    remainChars = MAX - document.getElementById("message").value.length;
    document.getElementById("count").style.color = "#1F1787";
}
```

}

```
function vToggle ()
{
if ( document.getElementById("darkSide").style.display == "none" )
{
    document.getElementById("darkSide").style.display           = "block";
    document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display             = "block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("darkSide").style.display           = "none";
    document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display             = "none";

}
```

}

Comment: If it's being called onload you have a call to vToggle somewhere, but it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: The only call to vToggle() function is on that "input" and onclick event. The tag <body> has no onload event nor function.

Comment: I also tried to change the name from vToggle() to vTogglePopup(), just to be sure there is no other function with the same name (and there is not). It still happens.

Comment: Then are you sure it's being called?  if you put an alert in vtoggle it is displayed onload?  Maybe the default styles for those elements handled by vtoggle are not what you expected.

Comment: Would you be able to post the full `.js` file?

Comment: I posted the entire fil .js now, I hope it's more understandable

Comment: @Francesco were you able to try the answer I posted?

Comment: It's interesting. If I add the alert as you suggest, it's not shown onload, but only when I click. I check the CSS and I let you know.

Comment: Kevin, you are right! I think I set the style property display: block on my CSS for a previous test and I forgot to change it again to display: none. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that was @James that suggested that :)

Comment: Kevin You are right!  Thank you James for solving the problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your `.js` file and removing `onClick` from your `HTML`:

```
document.getElementById('accept').onclick = vToggle;
```

Comment: I tried, but it's still invoked onload (I flushed browser cache and checked the  .js file was updated).

Comment: @Francesco I've updated my code with a new solution, see if that does the trick. This will replace the `addEventListener` that I suggested earlier, but you still will leave `onClick` out of the HTML (as general programming practice, I find you're better off holding all event calls within the `.js` file rather than the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

James found the problem as he said in his comment. "Then are you sure it's being called? if you put an alert in vtoggle it is displayed onload? Maybe the default styles for those elements handled by vtoggle are not what you expected. "

I checked my CSS and the display property was set to "block" instead of "none", because I did a test and I forgot to set again the right property on CSS. Thank you!